# insert form data as json array using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to insert my form data into database using json array, I googled many
links but did not get what I required that because of I search in wrong way.

My aim is to collect my form data in JSON array which I entered and store it into database how should I achieve that.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to use `serialize` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: can you give me a example of code

Comment: you can't have spent very long searching. Here's a complete example of doing almost exactly this from beginning to end. https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/ It was the second link on the google search I did of "php ajax submit". Incidentally there's no particular need to submit the form as JSON, it's easier just to serialize it like a regular postback would.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like :

```
var jsonData = '[{"dataset1": {"data1":"data1", "data2":"data2", "data3":"data3"}}]';
var data = {'action': 'action_name', 'data': jsonData};

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    //Your Code
}
```

You can also build your data as :

```
var jsonData = '[{"data1":"data1", "data2":"data2", "data3":"data3"}]';
```

You can also submit as :

```
var serialform = $("#formName").serialize();
var data = {'action': 'action_name', 'data': serialform};

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    //Your Code
}
```